# To print the reverse of a given number in java lang

Tags: java, while-loop, reverse

I have found examples which imported java.util.scanner and used reverse and scanner keys. Im a beginner and I tried a simpler way, though I am not getting the right output. please find the mistake in my code.

```
public class ReverseNum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=234,n,x;

    n=i%10;
    x=n;

    while(i>=0){

        i=(i/10)-n;
        n=i%10;
        x=(x*10)+n;
        System.out.print(x);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Go lexicographic instead of using math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 234, n;
        while (i > 0) {
            n = i % 10;
            i = i / 10;
            System.out.print(n);
        }
}
```

hope this is what you wanted...

Comment: wow, so we don't have to use a 3rd variable? and this even gives zeroes back. That's great to know.

Answer (score 4):

There, I fixed it for you.

```
class HelloWorld{
 public static void main(String args[]){

  int i=2340,n;
  while(i>0){
    n=i%10;
    i=(i/10);
    System.out.print(n);
  }

 }
}
```

You can also do this without math operations.

```
int i=234;

System.out.print(new StringBuffer(i+"").reverse().toString());
```

Comment: But if the number ends with zeroes, it doesn't give back those zeroes. we can use this if we dont want zeroes in the output . Thank you .

Comment: @ShrutiDev Why do you say it doesn't work with zeros. It works, please see https://ideone.com/pFM3oe

Comment: yeah. I put print(x) instead of n. but then should'nt we do away completely with the     x=(x*10)+n;     statement because we are not using it?

Comment: Yes, it is pointless now. Unless it's for a class, however, you should stick with the second method.

Answer (score 1):

**Program 1: Reverse a number using while Loop**

The program will prompt user to input the number and then it will reverse the same number using while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ReverseNumberWhile{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      int num=0;
      int reversenum =0;
      System.out.println("Input your number and press enter: ");
      //This statement will capture the user input
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      //Captured input would be stored in number num
      num = in.nextInt();
      //While Loop: Logic to find out the reverse number
      while( num != 0 ){
          reversenum = reversenum * 10;
          reversenum = reversenum + num%10;
          num = num/10;
      }

      System.out.println("Reverse of input number is: "+reversenum);
    }
}
```

Output:

`Input your number and press enter:`

`145689`

```
Reverse of input number is:

986541
```

http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/java-program-to-reverse-a-number/

Comment: yeah this is what i was talking about. but i didnt want the complicated imported package statements. I wanted a simple version which I found in the above comments. thanks though.